# Запрос для SQL. Как реализовать?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, ms-access

Для задачи необходимо 2 таблицы:

1. SPJ (таблица поставок: Номер поставщика n_post, Номер детали n_det, Номер изделия n_izd, Количество kol).
2. P (таблица деталей: Номер детали n_det, Цвет color).

Задача:

> Необходимо получить такие номера изделий, детали для которых
>   поставляются всеми поставщиками, среди поставляемых деталей которого
>   есть детали красного цвета.

Но как реализовать запрос?
Вот, что уже есть:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n_izd 
FROM SPJ 
WHERE n_post in 
(SELECT n_post from SPJ 
WHERE n_det in 
(SELECT n_det FROM P 
WHERE color='Красный'));
```

То есть, номера поставщиков, которые поставляют детали красного цвета, найдены. Что делать дальше?

Пример входных данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выход: J4

Comment: Я, может, не соображаю уже, но мне вообще непонятно, что должно быть на выходе. Плюс должна быть еще таблица с изделиями... Если можете, приведите конкретный пример (данные и что ожидается на выходе). Или мож кто еще другой тут разберется, что к чему.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов Таблица с изделиями  есть (номер изделия, название изделия, город), но мне показалось, что в данном задании она не будет использоваться. Как я вижу алгоритм: находим детали красного цвета -> находим поставщиков, которые поставляют детали красного цвета -> далее каким-то образом находим изделия, которые НЕ состоят из деталей, которые поставляют НЕ "красные" поставщики (т.е., состоят только из тех деталей, которые поставляют только красные поставщики).
Пример сейчас постараюсь прикрепить к заданию в фото.
На самом деле, очень запутанная формулировка у задания...

Comment: А что не так с Вашим запросом, он же вроде правильный и делает как раз то, что нужно - дает все изделия красных поставщиков?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов по условию должны выдаваться изделия, состоящие только из деталей красных поставщиков. а мой запрос выдает все изделия, в состав которых входит хотя бы одна деталь красного поставщика.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов отредактировала вопрос, добавила входные и выходные данные. Как я понимаю, на выходе остается одно изделие J4, в состав которого не входят детали P3 и P5, которые являются деталями не красного поставщика S2.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, у меня получилось то, что нужно. Получаем все изделия "некрасных" поставщиков и исключаем их из результата:

```
SELECT n_izd FROM SPJ WHERE n_izd NOT IN (
    SELECT n_izd FROM SPJ WHERE n_post NOT IN (
        SELECT n_post FROM SPJ JOIN P ON P.n_det = SPJ.n_det WHERE P.color = 'Красный'
    )
) GROUP BY n_izd
```

Не уверен, что это лучший запрос, который можно было составить, но он работает )